# Repeates call glBufferData failed to allocate memory for new buffer

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

In initialization of a renderer, VBOs are created and binded to GL_ARRAY_BUFFER or GL_ELEMENTS_ARRAY_BUFFER and there are three vertices in the first. Calling glBufferData to cache these three vertices' attribute to GPU.
Such as:

```
InitVBO() {

    vboArray = new int[4];

    GLES20.glGenBuffers(4, vboArray, 0);

    poseBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(poseLength * Float.SIZE / Byte.SIZE).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
    UpdatePose(); // fill array data to FloatBuffer

    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboArray[VBO_VERTEX]);
    GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, poseLength * Float.SIZE / Byte.SIZE, poseBuf, GLES20.GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);    // poseBuf initialized capacity is 9 * 4

    GLES20.glGetBufferParameteriv(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GLES20.GL_BUFFER_SIZE, params, 0);  // Get params[0] is 36

    colorBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(colorLength * Float.SIZE / Byte.SIZE).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
    UpdateColor(); // fill array data to FloatBuffer
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboArray[VBO_GRID_COLOR]);
    GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorLength * Float.SIZE / Byte.SIZE, gridColorBuf, GLES20.GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    ...
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

Then, it receive vertices data from TCP Network Msg in a child thread. Vertices' number is more than three. I recalled glBufferData:

```
UpdateVBO(){

    poseBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(poseLength * Float.SIZE / Byte.SIZE).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
    UpdatePose(); // fill array data to FloatBuffer
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboArray[VBO_VERTEX]);
    GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, poseLength * Float.SIZE / Byte.SIZE, poseBuf, GLES20.GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);  // poseBuf has been updated with capacity 12 * 4

    GLES20.glGetBufferParameteriv(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GLES20.GL_BUFFER_SIZE, pnew, 0);  // get pnew[0] is 0

    ...

    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

Why does not OpenGL ES Server allocate memory for the new buffer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer.

The significant error of my program is that I should not update Buffer cache in child thread of the program.

If I create a function called by child thread to update vertices poseBuf, and update VBO cache in draw function. This problem will be solved.